# React Native Profiler - FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, profiler, react-native-sectionlist

I'm just trying out Profiler for the performance. `FlatList` and the `renderItem` component renders only **1** time. But the `VirtualizedList` renders **17** times.

Is there a way to optimize `VirtualizedList`?

Attaching screenshot for reference,

**Flatlist**

[image]

**Item Component**

[image]

**VirtualizedList**

[image]

**FlatList Component:**

```
<FlatList 
 data={takeawayList} 
 renderItem={this.renderItem} 
 keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
```

Comment: Flatlist is the wrapper of VirtualizedList, and VirtualizedList is rendered every time when its pass the visible area

Comment: @NishargShah yes, correct. But does it causes performance issue?

Comment: If you have a plain array, you can use Flatlist but with immutable data you must use `VirtualizedList`. if your data is a plain array, there is no performance issue